# Adding hours and mins in date - java calendar class

Tags: java, date, calendar, addition

I need to append 23 Hrs and 59 mins in the date using the Java calendar class.
e.g. 17/03/2022 - has java Date as a datatype  - mapped to Date in Oracle
need to be stored in the database as  17/03/2022 23.59.00 - has Timestamp as data type.

I got the following function which works in most cases, but sometimes the date goes to the next day with the timestamp of 00.00.00 .

```
public Date addHoursToJavaUtilDate(Date date, int hours,int mins) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours); //hours = 23
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, mins);    //mins = 59
        return (Date) calendar.getTime();
    }
```

Why does it works in most of the cases but not all the time? Will reducing the number of mins to 30 will help me?

Answer (score 1):

Do you *not* have the chance to use `java.time.*` classes?

I know you specified `Calendar` usage, but notice how much simplicity you're missing: (written in Kotlin for easier readability)

```
val yourDate: LocalDateTime = ... // (or if you have TimeZone info, it would be `ZonedDateTime`)

val newDate = yourDate.plusHours(23).plusMinutes(59)
```

that's it.

Comment: `plus*` can be *dangerous* (if the corresponding fields are not zero) and confusing if some developer does not know that (I would prefer `LocalDate.atTime()` - or at least `withMinute()` and `withHour()`)

Comment: Care to elaborate? What do you mean by the corresponding fields not being zero?

Comment: I don't get it, why would you use `now()`? The  OP has a date, so you'd do `LocalDateTime.of(... hour, minute, 0) //0 if you don't want the seconds` but that's not part of the date handling. If the OP wants to store a different format in the database, it can be easily transformed. The question is "I need to add 23 hours, and 59 minutes to a date", we don't know what `date` he's working with. The OP has a date with no time component (apparently) and wants to ensure the date becomes the last minute of said date.

Comment: I'd argue that what you're describing (modifying a date whose components aren't zero and can therefore go beyond the perceived boundaries you have in your head) is part of the reason why you don't use calendar, date, and any of these old classes, and why you ought to understand how to operate with date/times, what timezones are, etc. If your intervals aren't tied with a timeline, then it's simply time arithmetic.

Comment: I think I did not make it clear. Date is coming from jsp as dd/mm//yyyy . It is a job vacancy closing date on the website. But the job needs to be on the website till midnight, that's why I need to append 23.59 as a timestamp so that job stays on the website till midnight. Now I do not want to change jsp. so I wanted to add 23.59 in the timestamp which works most of the time. But in some cases it goes to next day,

Comment: @user16320675 makes sense! now, reading what the OP wants... If you have a day, month, and year, make a `LocalDateTime.Of(day, month, year, 23, 59, 00)` If you also want to ensure timezone changes don't affect you, ensure you use the `ZonedDateTime` version, and provide the TimeZone info/Offset that is appropriate for your use-case. Then proceed to store that in any format you wish in your database; remember to include TZ info *if you have it/use it*.

Answer (score 1):

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

`Calendar`, actually `GregorianCalendar`, was replaced by `ZonedDateTime`.

## Data and time

Capturing the current moment requires a time zone. For any given moment the date and the time can vary around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

You want to set the time of day to 23:59:00. We can produce a new `ZonedDateTime` object based on the old one but with a different time of day. Be aware that your specified time of day will be altered if not valid on that date in that zone, because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 23 , 59 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt2359 = zdt.with( lt ) ;
```

Alternatively, you could capture the current date only. Then assemble a `ZonedDateTime` from the three parts of date, time, and zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now ( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

## Database access

For database access, do not use legacy class `Timestamp`. Use `OffsetDateTime` to record a moment in SQL databases.

Write this value to a database column of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt2359.toOffsetDateTime() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

---

Caveat: If you are trying to represent the end of a day, your `23:59` is the wrong approach. You are missing the last minute of the day. And some dates in some zones are not 24 hours long. Instead, learn about tracking time with Half-Open approach.